# audio session is not being started when call is received in SIP

Tags: sip

```
This is the error when i receive a call when i accept incomming call in SIP.
```

11-28 14:25:35.669: E/AudioRecord(21143): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
    11-28 14:25:35.679: E/AudioRecord-JNI(21143): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
    11-28 14:25:35.679: E/android.media.AudioRecord(21143): Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
    11-28 14:25:35.679: E/org.doubango.ngn.media.NgnProxyAudioProducer(21143): prepare(0) failed
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): ***[DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "tdav_session_audio_start()" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): file: "src/audio/tdav_session_audio.c" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): line: "425" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): MSG: tdav_session_av_start(audio) failed
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143):** [DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "_tmedia_session_mgr_start()" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): file: "src/tmedia_session.c" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): line: "2370" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): MSG: Failed to start audio session
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): **[DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "tmedia_session_mgr_set_ro()" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): file: "src/tmedia_session.c" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): line: "1526" 
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/tinyWRAP(21143): MSG: Failed to re-start session at index = 0
    11-28 14:25:35.719: E/broadcast is received(21143): to handle media event
    11-28 14:25:35.799: E/tinyWRAP(21143): ***[DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "tsip_dialog_invite_process_ro()" 
    11-28 14:25:35.799: E/tinyWRAP(21143): file: "src/dialogs/tsip_dialog_invite.c" 
    11-28 14:25:35.799: E/tinyWRAP(21143): line: "508" 
    11-28 14:25:35.799: E/tinyWRAP(21143): MSG: Failed to set remote offer

```
 below is the method to accept incomming call



  private boolean acceptCall() {
            if (mAVSession != null) {
                return mAVSession.acceptCall();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is due to native service is not being started.check whether native service is registered in menifest or not or go through the native service class